# If the set of values , for which a function has positive derivative , is dense then is the function increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function such that $A:=${ $x \in \mathbb R :f'(x)>0$ } is dense  in $\mathbb R$ , then is it true that $f$ is an increasing function ? What  happens if $f'$ is also continuous  ?

Comment: Is $f'$ continuous?

Comment: @Maximiliano: Not necessarily ....

Comment: This is only a partial answer so I'll leave it as a comment. It is clear that your question is equivalent to the following: let $g$ be a derivative and assume that $g$ takes positive values on a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$, is it true that $g$ cannot take negative values? I would think that the answer is no and that a counter-example is given by [Darboux functions][1].


  [1]: http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Darboux_%28analyse%29#Les_fonctions_de_Darboux

Comment: I wonder why you added "What happens if $f′$ is also increasing ?". In this case it is easy, isn't it? Then $f'$ cannot take non-positive values, and so $f$ must be strictly increasing.

Comment: If $f'$ is continuous, then it must always be nonnegative and so $f$ is increasing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is **no**.

Take a look at [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2318996?uid=3738016&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21104172836991). The corollary on p. 353 ensures that for any two disjoint countable dense subsets $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}$, there exists an everywhere differentiable function $H$ such that $H'>0$ on $A$ and $H'<0$ on $B$. Note that this function is monotone on no subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$.

I should give credit to user JLT from the French maths forum www.les-mathematiques.net, who pointed out this article to me on [this thread](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?4,994549).

**Edit:** Other references for such a counter-example include the paper mentioned by Dave Renfro in the comments below, also *A Second Course on Real Functions* by Rooij and Schikhof, example 13.2 p.80 (thank you Seirios for mentioning this to me in [the French thread](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?4,994549)).

Comment: A paper with more historical information about such functions, and which has the additional advantage of not being behind a pay-wall is: Jiri Blazek, E. Borák, and Jan Malý, [*On Köpcke and Pompeiu functions*](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/no_cache/dms/load/img/?IDDOC=104431), **Casopis Pro Pestování Matematiky** 103 (1978), 53-61.

Comment: @Seub: Thank you very much for this wonderful reference. This will now be my standard reference for (1) A function which is **everywhere** differentiable with **bounded** derivative, but the derivative is not Riemann integrable, (2) A function with $\{H' > 0\}$ and $\{H' < 0\}$ both dense (even with some freedom to choose members of these sets), (3) A construction of a set $A$ such that $I \cap A$ and $I \cap A^c$ both have positive measure for each open interval $I$, (4) A function which has local max. and min. in every open interval (and is differentiable).